# okhttp3 passing parameter with "--data {json}"

Tags: java, okhttp

How can I pass parameter with "--data {json}" on okHttp3?  Do I need to add it in the headers like below?  Or its not on the header, it need to be on another object?

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
            .addHeader("data", "{json}")
            .url(url)
```

Please let me know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must add to `RequestBody` :

```
final String BOUNDARY = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder(BOUNDARY)
                                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)  
                                    .addFormDataPart("data", JsonData)
                                    //.addFormDataPart("otherPara", otherPara)
                                    .build();                       
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();
```

Comment: Thanks [D T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1497597/d-t)